# MySQL LIMIT question

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using pagination for my search results but for some reason my pagination is not working correctly with my search script. I can't seem to find the correct place to put the `LIMIT $start, $display` in my search query code where ever I put it in my code it displays the pagination all wrong. Can some one please help me?

Here is the part of my PHP & MySQL search code.

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "sitename");

    $search_explode = explode(" ", $search);

    foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
        $x++;
        if($x == 1){
            $construct .= "article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        } else {
            $construct .= "OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }

    }

$construct = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
              INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
              WHERE $construct";
$run =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $construct);

$foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($run);
```

SQL statement.

```
SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id WHERE article_content LIKE '%find%' OR title LIKE '%find%' OR summary LIKE '%find%'OR article_content LIKE '%this%' OR title LIKE '%this%' OR summary LIKE '%this%'OR article_content LIKE '%article%' OR title LIKE '%article%' OR summary LIKE '%article%' LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: to add `$search_each = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$search_each);` would be nice. or use prepared statements

Answer (score 2):

The basic syntax of SELECT is:

```
SELECT [fields]
FROM [tables [JOIN tables]]
WHERE [conditions]
GROUP BY [fields]
HAVING [conditions]
ORDER BY [fields]
LIMIT [limit]
```

So, right at the end after the WHERE conditions.

Here's the documentation which shows the [full syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html).

Comment: But where exactly in my code? I tried everything but with no success :(

Comment: I don't believe you really tried it. He said right after the WHERE conditions, thats as simple as it can be explained. 

"WHERE $conditions LIMIT..."

Comment: I did it displays my pagination all wrong for example if I have 40 records it will only display one and not the rest.

Comment: @lone: That looks like something in the `WHERE` clause is wrong.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo any clues to what it is?

Comment: @lone: Do you get all the results when you omit the `LIMIT` part?

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo for some reason it will only display 1 result when it should display about ten at a time.

Comment: @Daniel Vassallo yes I get all the results when I leave out the LIMIT

Comment: @lone
What exactly are the values that are getting passed to the LIMIT ($start and $display)?

Comment: Ok that looks fine.
Then maybe print out the whole SQL statements in both cases and add it to your original post. Maybe also the result sets (or a part of it if they are too big).

Answer (score 1):

Are you remembering to insert spaces into your string snippets as you build the query? Remember that PHP doesn't put anything into a string that you don't put there yourself.

```
$x = 'a';
$x .= 'b';
```

gives you `ab`, not `a[space]b`. Your `$construct` will be full of syntax errors if more than one search term is entered, as the subsequent `OR` will be attached directly to the end of any previous added search terms. You'll end up with something like:

```
[...snip...] OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%OR article_content LIKE[...snip...]
                                           ^^--syntax error here.
```

The same applies if you append the limit clause without making sure there's a space between the end of your query and the "LIMIT X,Y" text you append.

Answer (score 0):

This should show the first 10 rows:

```
SELECT      users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
INNER JOIN  users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE       article_content LIKE '%something%'
LIMIT       0, 10
```

Changing the `LIMIT` clause to the following should display rows from 11 to 20:

```
LIMIT       10, 10
```

Also note that you should probably escape your `$construct` string as [@Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/col-shrapnel) suggested in a comment above. This is to avoid [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601300/what-is-sql-injection).

In addition, you may want to investigate using [Full Text Indexing](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1304) instead.

Comment: I'd add that LIMIT clause parameters should be explicitly cast/evaluated to int, to be protected from injection as well

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitename");
mysqli_select_db($mysqli, "sitename");

    $search_explode = explode(" ", $search);

    foreach($search_explode as $search_each) {
        $x++;
        if($x == 1){
            $construct .= " article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        } else {
            $construct .= " OR article_content LIKE '%$search_each%' OR title LIKE '%$search_each%' OR summary LIKE '%$search_each%'";
        }

    }

$construct = "SELECT users.*, users_articles.* FROM users_articles
              INNER JOIN users ON users_articles.user_id = users.user_id
              WHERE $construct";
$construct .= " LIMIT 0, 10" ; // replace 0, 10 with your variables

$run =  mysqli_query($mysqli, $construct);

$foundnum = mysqli_num_rows($run);
```